# Prove the claim

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove the following Claim:

"Claim: Suppose sets $A$ and $B$ are finite subsets of a finite set $U$

Then $|A| \cap |B| \ge |A| + |B| - |U|$"

By subtracting $|A| \cap |B|$ from both sides and adding $|U|$ to both sides I get

$|U| \ge |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$

which results in (by the inclusion-exclusion principle)

$|U| \ge |A \cup B|$

Am I going about this correctly? Is my result enough to prove the claim?

Comment: That's how I would have done it. What do you mean is it enough? Can the size of $A\cup B$ be bigger than the size of $U$?

Comment: Good point. Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle the argument  is not correct. You have shown correctly  that if what you  hope is true is indeed true, then we reach an assertion that is definitely true. But you need to check that the steps you took are **reversible**. This can be done. A correct writeup might go as follows.
We have
$$|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|.$$
Clearly $|U|\ge |A\cup B|$. It follows that
$$|U|\ge |A|+|B|-|A\cap B|.$$
Now manipulation gives the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't think of it that way.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the *ingredients* were exactly the same as yours. Yours could have also been made correct by observing that your implications (steps) are reversible.